# Change the css-ribbon position from right to left on a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to change the position of css-ribbon from right-side to the left-side and the direction of ribbon should also be changed accordingly on the left side.The items like some images and text will be placed in the div and these elements will not be disturbed by the ribbon itself.And this is my html code.

```
<div class="content-box">
        <div id="ribbon-container">
            <a href="#" id="ribbon">CSS-Ribbon</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my css code below.

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    /* Standard Reset, and we're adding box-sizing:border-box because it's awesome. */
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
}
.content-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 94px auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    /* So we can position the banner within the box */
    background: gray;
    border: 5px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
#ribbon-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: -20px;
    overflow: visible;
    /* so we can see the pseudo-elements we're going to add to the anchor */
    font-size: 18px;
    /* font-size and line-height must be equal so we can account for the height of the banner */
    line-height: 18px;
}
#ribbon-container:before {
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 29px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    /* These 4 border properties create the first part of our drop-shadow */
    border-bottom: 29px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-right: 29px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-left: 29px solid transparent;
}
#ribbon-container:after {
    /* This adds the second part of our dropshadow */
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 58px;
    right: 3px;
}
#ribbon-container a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    /* allows us to position our pseudo-elements properly */
    background: #0089d0;
    overflow: visible;
    height: 58px;
    margin-left: 29px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#ribbon-container a:after {
    /* this creates the "folded" part of our ribbon */
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid #004a70;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
}
#ribbon-container a:before {
    /* this creates the "forked" part of our ribbon */
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -29px;
    border-top: 29px solid #0089d0;
    border-bottom: 29px solid #0089d0;
    border-right: 29px solid transparent;
    border-left: 29px solid transparent;
}
#ribbon-container a:hover {
    background: #009ff1;
}
#ribbon-container a:hover:before {
    /* this makes sure that the "forked" part of the ribbon changes color with the anchor on :hover */
    border-top: 29px solid #009ff1;
    border-bottom: 29px solid #009ff1;
}
```

Comment: so you simply picked a ready code from here : https://www.designcouch.com/home/why/2013/03/21/pure-css-ribbon-banner/ and you want us to change it for you? .. better read and unerstand the code if you want to learn, the code is well explained there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a live fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/covn07uh/14/

HTML (The same):

```
<div class="content-box">
    <div id="ribbon-container">
        <a href="#" id="ribbon">CSS-Ribbon</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    /* Standard Reset, and we're adding box-sizing:border-box because it's awesome. */
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
}
.content-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 94px auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    /* So we can position the banner within the box */
    background: gray;
    border: 5px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
#ribbon-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: -20px;
    overflow: visible;
    /* so we can see the pseudo-elements we're going to add to the anchor */
    font-size: 18px;
    /* font-size and line-height must be equal so we can account for the height of the banner */
    line-height: 18px;
}
#ribbon-container:before {
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
    border-top: 29px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    /* These 4 border properties create the first part of our drop-shadow */
    border-bottom: 29px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-left: 29px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-right: 29px solid transparent;
}
#ribbon-container:after {
    /* This adds the second part of our dropshadow */
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    right: 58px;
    left: 3px;
}
#ribbon-container a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    /* allows us to position our pseudo-elements properly */
    background: #0089d0;
    overflow: visible;
    height: 58px;
    margin-right: 29px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#ribbon-container a:after {
    /* this creates the "folded" part of our ribbon */
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 0;
    border-top: 15px solid #004a70;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
}
#ribbon-container a:before {
    /* this creates the "forked" part of our ribbon */
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -29px;
    border-top: 29px solid #0089d0;
    border-bottom: 29px solid #0089d0;
    border-left: 29px solid transparent;
    border-right: 29px solid transparent;
}
#ribbon-container a:hover {
    background: #009ff1;
}
#ribbon-container a:hover:before {
    /* this makes sure that the "forked" part of the ribbon changes color with the anchor on :hover */
    border-top: 29px solid #009ff1;
    border-bottom: 29px solid #009ff1;
}
```

Comment: the question is bad but let at least make the answer good .. you may add some comments to highlight the changes you have done to the code.

Answer (score -1):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
}
.content-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 94px auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
     background: gray;
    border: 5px solid white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
#ribbon-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: -20px;
    overflow: visible;
     font-size: 18px;
     line-height: 18px;
}
#ribbon-container:before {
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
 /* here right will be zero to move ribbon right to left */
    border-top: 29px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
     border-bottom: 29px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    border-right: 29px solid transparent;
 /* in same way border right will be transparent instead of border left */
    border-left: 29px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
#ribbon-container:after {
     content: "";
    height: 3px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3px;
    right: 58px;
 /* here just left property is renamed with right property */
    left: 4px;
}
#ribbon-container a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
     background: #0089d0;
    overflow: visible;
    height: 58px;
    margin-right: 29px;
 /* here margin left is replaced with margin right */
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#ribbon-container a:after {
     content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 0;
 /* right is replaced with left */
    border-top: 15px solid #004a70;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
 /* here border left is transparent instead if border right */
 }
#ribbon-container a:before {
    /* this creates the "forked" part of our ribbon */
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -29px;
 /* here left is replaced with right */
    border-top: 29px solid #0089d0;
    border-bottom: 29px solid #0089d0;
    border-right: 29px solid transparent;
    border-left: 29px solid transparent;
}
#ribbon-container a:hover {
    background: #009ff1;
}
#ribbon-container a:hover:before {
    /* this makes sure that the "forked" part of the ribbon changes color with the anchor on :hover */
    border-top: 29px solid #009ff1;
    border-bottom: 29px solid #009ff1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box">
        <div id="ribbon-container">
            <a href="#" id="ribbon">CSS-Ribbon</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation so as to make your answer more useful to readers?